# Memory leak with map

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, dictionary

I can't clear the map memory (I checked by [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind)).

```
#include <map>

class testMap {
    public:
        testMap(){}
        ~testMap();

        void insert_map(int, int);

    private:
          std::map<int,int> _map;
};

void testMap::insert_map(int i, int j){
    _map.insert( pair<int, int>(i,j));
}
```

I tried `_map.clear()`, `erase()`, deleted `_map->second` manually but not still no luck.

---

Thanks for all replies. Actually `map` alone is not a problem but `map` with a singleton is causing a leak. What's wrong with the code below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Object.h"

#include<boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Singleton {
    public:

        // A wrapper around Object class
        class object
        {
            public:
                object() : _object(new Object())
                    {}
                Object get(void)
                    { return _object.get(); }
            private:
                boost::shared_ptr<Object> _object;
        };

        object insert_new(const std::string key)
        {
            _object_maps.insert( pair<string,object>( key, object() ));
            return _object_maps.find( key )->second;
            //_test_object = object();
            //return _test_object;  // Leak goes away if I don't use map.
        }

        static Singleton* Instance();
        void Print();

    protected:
        Singleton(){}
        ~Singleton();

    private:
        static Singleton* _instance;

        std::map<std::string, object > _object_maps;
        object _test_object;
};

Singleton* Singleton::_instance = 0;

Singleton* Singleton::Instance() {
    if( _instance ==0 )
    {
        _instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return _instance;
}

void Singleton::Print() {
    std::cout << " Hi I am a singleton object" << std::endl;
}

Singleton::~Singleton()
{
    _object_maps.clear();
}
```

From another code I was calling by

```
    Singleton::object _test_object(Singleton::Instance()->insert_new("TEST"));
```

Is there a problem? I am getting a Valgrind error, like

```
      ==19584== 17 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 31,429 of 52,291
      ==19584==    at 0x69A1642: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
      ==19584==    by 0x772CB0A: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
      ==19584==    by 0x772D904: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
       ==19584==    by 0x772DB16: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
       ==19584==    by 0xBF1BC17: test::test() (test.C:34)
       ==19584==    by 0xBF1DB66: G__testDict_143_0_1(G__value*, char const*, G__param*, int) (testDict.C:190)
       ==19584==    by 0x70EA4E5: Cint::G__ExceptionWrapper(int (*)(G__value*, char const*, G__param*, int), G__value*, char*, G__param*, int) (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x71EF2E4: G__call_cppfunc (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x71C0095: G__interpret_func (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x71AF883: G__getfunction (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x71D8CC1: G__new_operator (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x718D07F: G__getexpr (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x717724E: G__define_var (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x71FDEC6: G__defined_type (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x7201A6D: G__exec_statement (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x71BF6C8: G__interpret_func (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x71AF62F: G__getfunction (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x718437D: G__getitem (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x7189F12: G__getexpr (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
       ==19584==    by 0x719713F: G__calc_internal (in /afs/rhic.bnl.gov/@sys/opt/phenix/root-5.17.01/lib/libCint.so)
```

Comment: What output do you get from valgrind?

Comment: Can you also show the call that you're making to create/destroy the testMap object?

Comment: Also, leading underscore in your map name? bad!!!

Comment: @George, I thought so too until somebody informed me of the actual rules - it's OK in the scope of a class. I think this is a pretty common convention for member variables.

Comment: @Sen: what compiler did you use?

Comment: @Mark: It is OK... In the scope of a class...  And as long as the first character after the underscore is lower case...  It is hard to argue that the exact rules are even worth remembering when "never start an identifier with underscore" is so simple and always works.

Comment: @Nemo, I prefer the simpler rule too and I live by it. I've just learned never to complain when someone violates my simplified view of the world.

Comment: @Mark: With an attitude like that, how do you hope ever to gain a reputation as an Internet jerk? :-)

Comment: @Mark: Now I'm an internet jerk :(

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**:
you explicitly declared but not defined the destructor (forgot `{}`).

**Long answer**:

1. Your code does not even compile. Missing `{}` in class destructor and `std::` in front of `pair`.
2. Corrected and completed with `main`:

   ```
   #include <map>

   class testMap {
     public:
       testMap() {}
       ~testMap() {};

       void insert_map(int, int);

     private:
       std::map<int,int> _map;
   };

   void testMap::insert_map(int i, int j) {
       _map.insert(std::pair<int, int>(i,j));
   }

   int main() {
       testMap t;
       t.insert_map(12, 34);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Compiled on 32-bit Ubuntu 11.04:

   ```
   g++ leak.cpp -o leak
   ```
4. Run under `valgrind` supervision:

   ```
   valgrind ./leak
   ==20773== Memcheck, a memory error detector
   ==20773== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
   ==20773== Using Valgrind-3.6.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
   ==20773== Command: ./leak
   ==20773== 
   ==20773== 
   ==20773== HEAP SUMMARY:
   ==20773==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   ==20773==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 24 bytes allocated
   ==20773== 
   ==20773== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
   ==20773== 
   ==20773== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
   ==20773== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 6)
   ```
5. No memory leakage.

*Probably* your compiler auto-defines a completely empty class destructor (because of missing `{}`), not auto-calling anymore on exit the private member map destructor.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm curious to see the long answer, because I don't know how it could hurt other than to generate a linker error.

Comment: @Mark: I think the point here is a strange compiler behaviour in presence of a syntax error. Just asked the OP what compiler he uses.

Comment: @Vanni: I'd be shocked if a compiler autogenerated the destructor when it's been user declared... should be a linker error.  But, +1 for illustrating that the general usage of map is sound given a sane compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
{
    std::map<int,int> empty_map;
    empty_map.swap(_map);
}
```

(At least, this is the usual way to convince a standard library container actually to release its memory.)

Comment: Or more succinctly, `std::map<int, int>().swap(_map);`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Yours has the advantage of deallocating the memory immediately, rather than when `empty_map` goes out of scope.  Mine has the advantage of being easier to read for someone new to the idiom.  "Succinct" is not always "better".

Comment: I never said "better", for a reason.